# wmic to get lastmodified data on a file across a network

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to get lastmodified data using a batch file across a network

the line of code I am using to get the info is

```
wmic datafile where name="%file:\=\\%" get lastmodified
```

This works fine on local files but I get a `No Instance(s) Available` error when I try to use that line on a network file such as `\\networkshare\folder\file.txt`.

Answer (score 3):

`datafile` does not support UNC paths.

You have two options

1. Connect to the remote node and ask for the file, **knowing the local path** to the file **in the remote system**

```
    set "file=e:\somewhere\file.txt"
    wmic /node:serverName datafile where name="%file:\=\\%" get lastmodified
```

2. If you don't know the local paths in the remote system, it is necessary to map a drive letter to the network share to retrieve the needed information

Sample code

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Configure file
    set "file=\\server\share\folder\file.txt"

    rem Separate path and filename
    for %%a in ("%file%") do ( set "filePath=%%~dpa" & set "fileName=%%~nxa" )

    rem Change to target path and adapt file path if sucessful
    pushd "%filePath%" && (for %%a in (.\) do set "filePath=%%~fa")||(set "filePath=")

    rem If the current directory has changed, get file data and return to previous folder
    if defined filePath (
        wmic datafile where "name='%filePath:\=\\%%fileName%'" get LastModified
        popd
    )
```