# Query MSI Properties with Batch File

Tags: batch-file, windows-installer

Is there any way possible to query a MSI from a batch file without using any other method/tools? I am looking to pull things like ProductName, ProductVersion, and ProductCode. I can already accomplish this successfully with PS or VBS, but can't seem to figure out how to do this with only batch. Is this possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you have WMIC installed, you can use that to determine this information.

```
%__APPDIR__%wbem\wmic.exe datafile where "name='path\\to\\file.msi'" get /value
```

Make sure you double up the slashes in the path for this to work. So, use C:\test\folder\file.msi instead of C:\test\folder\file.msi

The information available here will be up to the publisher.

Comment: Well, the command appears to have worked, but I receive the following:
No Instance(s) Available.

Comment: Can you provide the exact command you used?

Comment: Command: WMIC DataFile Where "Name='\\\\server003\\converted\\msis\\colour.msi'" Get /Value   |   
Result: No Instance(s) Available.   |   
This specific MSI has the following properties as viewed with Orca: Manufacturer, ProductCode, ProductName, ProductVersion   |   
Thanx again.

Comment: Apparently, I don't have the ability to force CRLF, so I've added vertical lines to delineate the differences between lines in my response.

Comment: That is a limitation of UNC paths and WMIC. Please see this [link for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27266827/wmic-to-get-lastmodified-data-on-a-file-across-a-network)

Comment: Ahh, gotchya. So, moved it into the same folder as WMIC and ran same command and even though it did return some results, it is not returning any of the values I was looking for. Guess I'll just stick with my Powershell or VBS solution. Thanx again.